# How to set up the false result handler for vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I have set up a vlookup in VBA (excel) as shown below. When the result from vlookup is not found, it should return as blank but I received an error. How do I set up the false results handler?

```
Private Sub users()

Dim user As String
Dim result As Variant

user = Application.UserName
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(user, Worksheets("users").Range("A:B"), 2, False)

If IsError(result) Then result = ""


Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C18").Value = result

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I thought I was out of solutions and seek for help, I found a possible  answer.

```
Private Sub users()

Dim user As String
Dim result As Variant

user = Application.UserName

On Error Resume Next
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(user, Worksheets("users").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
If Err Then
result = ""
End If

Worksheets("発注ｴﾝﾄﾘｰ").Range("C18").Value = result

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two versions of `VLookup` available.  In this case you are better to use the other one.  Simply change your lookup to

```
result = Application.VLookup(user, Worksheets("users").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
```

and it will work.

the primary difference is how the functions handle errors. This version returns an error variable, `WorksheetFunction` version throws a runtime error (which you can handle with `On Error ...` if you prefer)

Comment: Very well, that works too. It shortens the code and doesn't even need on error resume next.